# Finding the general solution for a higher order different equation with constant coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation

I am given $y^{(8)}+y^{(6)}+y^{(4)}+y^{(2)}+ay=0$ where $a$ is a real number. The question asks for which values of $a$ does the equation have a real-valued solution which is never $0$.

Convert to characteristic equation: $r^8 + r^6 + r^4 + r^2 + a=0$

Our solution will be of the form $y(t)=C_1e^{r_1t}+...+C_8e^{r_8t}$. In order for this to never be zero, we need atleast one $C_i \neq 0$ and no two terms that are the same but opposite signs. I am struggling with manipulating the characteristic equation to figure out how $r$ and $a$ depend on each other. I tried factoring and rewriting, but I couldn't find any useful information. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Well it doesn't for $a=0$ since you will get a root with multiplicity and $$y(t)=1+t$$ solves the equation (and $y(0)=0$). You're on the right track, but keep in mind that all of the $r_k$ will be different since your solution is the sum of linearly independent solutions. You have to be careful of the case when $r_k = r_m$, since you will need to add a solution with root multiplicity.

Comment: Since the exponents on $r$ are all multiples of $2$, you might consider making the substitution $\tilde{r} = r^2$. I'm not promising this will solve it as I haven't tried to work it out, but it might be worth a try.

Comment: To start off: If $a > 0$ then the characteristic equation can only have complex roots, which cannot work since complex powers have an oscillating part.